# D3 graph not showing in Phonegap android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, d3.js

I am working on using Phonegap to create apps for Windows 8 and Android from my web application that makes use of D3.js graphs.

I am using the CLI method to create and build in phonegap and was able to create a test app for Windows 8, but I am having problems loading the Android app in the emulator. It builds and launches successfully according to the cmd, but it doesn't display on the emulator correctly.

I can see that it loads two buttons that I have included in the UI (you can see it top left), but the graph does not show up at all and I don't know what is wrong.

Anybody have any ideas about this? Do I have to wrap the D3 graph code in a webview control or something within the app or should it work as is (i.e. just including the code used to create the graph into the index.html file created by Phonegap)?

And then also, when using the emulator, how can I determine if there is a problem with the app?

[image: Android UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the logcat to look for Android errors.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Check out the the chrome debugger for browser errors.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

The Chrome debugger will likely be your best best. You may see errors related to PhoneGap initialization or missing files or no internet permissions, etc.

From there you may need to make some changes like adding permissions or rebuilding the Android platform inside your project. I've had a lot of trouble with PhoneGap in the past (and since stopped using it).